# Have each other

Tags: sentence-meaning

From the Godfather movie:

> *Kay:* Michael, why did you come here? Why? What do you want of me after
>   all this time? I've been writing and calling.
>
> *Michael:* I came here because I need you, because I care for you.
>
> *Kay:* Please, stop it Michael...
>
> *Michael:* Because, I want you to marry me
>
> *Kay:* It's too late.
>
> *Michael:* Please, Kay. I'll do anything you ask anything to make up for
>   what's happened to us. Because that's importatnt, Kay. **Becuase
>   what's important is that... we have each other. That we have a life
>   together**....

I didn't understand the exact meaning of ***we have each other*** and ***That we have a life together***. The first thought about that was that it has something todo with possessing each other, but it sounds totally nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often use **have** in the context of *being close to someone* and *being able to count on them*, *their love, support*; *making a life with someone*.

For instance:

> If I didn't have you, I couldn't imagine my life with someone else.

Here the speaker doesn't infer that she *possesses* the other person, but rather has a relationship with him, has him in her life, etc. Если бы тебя в моей жизни не было... *If I didn't have you in my life*.

Comment: I got the meaning of the first sentence, thanks. But what about the second? __We have a life together.__ That's not about being close to something (how can they be close to the life?)

Comment: Here together means "mutually" "in each other's company" "you and I"

Comment: I guess you could take **have** and **together** in two senses simultaneously:  They have been spending their lives **together** (in one another's company) and they **have** (possess as joint owners, **together**) that combined life.

Comment: I think "possess" is too literal. In this case, "have" has a meaning closer to "enjoy" a life in each other's company."

Answer (score 2):

We have each other is meaning:

> We use each other and one another to show that each person in a group of two or more people does something to the others.

From: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/each-other-one-another)

In this context, it is used to show that both of them will support and help each other.